# CSS-HTML : Mobile version text are overlapping

Tags: html, css

Asking for someone who is good in css designing.

The orange squares look ok when on desktop, but they overlap when seen in mobile. What's the best way to make mobile more presentable, where the 2nd line of squares won't overlap?

Desktop version
[image]

Mobile version

[image]

```css
.sublink {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sublink li {
  background-color: #F98D2B;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sublink">
  <li><a href="member.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Personal Details</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="memberorder.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Order History</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="memberverify.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Account Verification</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="membermails.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Messages</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Personally, I'd go for css flex :D  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below css. https://jsfiddle.net/kartik_bhalala/d63ohjgn/1/

```
.sublink {
    list-style-type:none; 
    margin-right:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
.sublink li{
    background-color: #F98D2B;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:18px;
    display: inline-block;    
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Identifying the Challenge

The problem here is that when you use `display: inline` you tell the component to behave like floating text - therefore, if the text is too long for the device to render on one line, it will break onto the next line. Because all the elements that you have are treated as one text-block - `line-height` will define how the vertical space is distributed.

You could use `display: inline-block` instead. So, the browser will try to render it as its own separate element. This will apply different styling options. Imagine two paragraphs. A modern alternative is to use `display: flex` on the parent item. It will distribute the available space onto the parts with a strategy of your choosing.

For example:

An item will grow bigger/smaller than you told it to be (e.g. by width: 200px) and flex will try to distribute space on other items that are smaller/bigger so that the item will be fitting.

## Which one to choose?

It depends. Display `inline-block` has been around for eons and is widely supported even by very old divices/browsers. It is simple and you can fix it with pretty much just one change. With flexbox you have more options, but you would need to set it up properly to work as intended. If you don't need it right away, you could as well just go with the `inline-block` variant.

## Solution with display: inline-block

```css
.sublink {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sublink li {
  background-color: #F98D2B;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sublink">
  <li><a href="member.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Personal Details</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="memberorder.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Order History</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="memberverify.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Account Verification</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="membermails.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Messages</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

## Solution with flexbox

```css
.sublink {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.sublink li {
  background-color: #F98D2B;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sublink">
  <li><a href="member.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Personal Details</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="memberorder.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Order History</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="memberverify.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Account Verification</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="membermails.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Messages</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using flex-box will best way to mobile more presentable

here is my example

```css
.sublink {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style-type:none; 
    margin-right:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
.sublink li{
    background-color: #F98D2B;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:18px;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sublink">
<li><a href="member.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Personal Details</span></a></li>
<li><a href="memberorder.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Order History</span></a></li>
<li><a href="memberverify.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Account Verification</span></a></li>
<li><a href="membermails.php"><span style="color:#ffffff">Messages</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Flexbox may be used here, but you won't have `display: inline` inside the child then.